# Order table html asc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function that adds rows to my table, but the problem is that it's not always in asc order, have a number column to sort the items.

I need reorder my table HTML acording to the column N°.

**It's my table:**

```
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| N°   |   COLUMN1     |    COLUMN2    |  COLUMN3  |
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| 2    |  AAAAAAAAAAAA |  XXXXXXXXXXXX |  00000000 |
| 1    |  BBBBBBBBBBBB |  YYYYYYYYYYYY |  00000000 |
| 3    |  CCCCCCCCCCCC |  ZZZZZZZZZZZZ |  00000000 |
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

**The result expected is:**

```
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| N°   |   COLUMN1     |    COLUMN2    |  COLUMN3  |
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
| 1    |  BBBBBBBBBBBB |  YYYYYYYYYYYY |  00000000 |
| 2    |  AAAAAAAAAAAA |  XXXXXXXXXXXX |  00000000 |
| 3    |  CCCCCCCCCCCC |  ZZZZZZZZZZZZ |  00000000 |
+------+---------------+---------------+-----------+
```

*Each column has an attribute order, looks like this:*

```
<tr data-order='2'>......</tr>
<tr data-order='1'>......</tr>
<tr data-order='3'>......</tr>
```

I try with the pluging [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) (It's working), but I would like to sort my table without additional plugin.

Thanks for help in advance! :)

**EDIT: Solution to the problem...**

as I had mentioned I have a function that adds a new tr.

```
function addnewTR(newOrder, new_tr){
    //Code
}
```

**First**, find if the order exist in the table, if exist set the tr to the variable.

```
$('#myTable tbody tr').each(function (i) {

    var _tr;
    var order = $(this).data("order");

    if (order_actual == newOrder) {
       _tr = this;
    };

});
```

**Second**, Check the position of `_tr` to insert my new element using [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) (if exist the order in the table) or [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) (if the order is new).

```
if (_tr !== undefined) {
   $(new_tr).insertAfter(_tr);
} else {
   $("#myTable tbody").append(new_tr);
}
```

Comment: There are numerous sorting scripts available. Rather than use one are you expecting someone here to write one for you? This isn't a coding service

Comment: @charlietfl it is true, but I would like to perform without using additional plugins

Comment: So you are expecting somone to write this for you then? That isn't how this site works.

Comment: @charlietfl not necessarily suggest any idea can not only write code

Comment: You need to first show your own attempts at writing this code. When, or if, you have problems with that code then please come back and ask us about those specific problems. Provide the code you're using, a full explanation of the problems you're having (what the code does, what it doesn't do that it should) and share your "*[MCVE]*" code so that we can reproduce your problem. It's not a particularly hard problem to solve, so searching using this site using your favourite search engine should yield some useful information and tips (although you will likely have to modify the code you find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a pure javascript solution. It does keep the original order thus you can say it's stable sorting.
Note :

1. I assumed you data-order only contains integers
2. Can have duplicate values for data-order
3. Sort in ASC order

Explanation:

1. You need to get  `<tr>` list from table
2. Store it on a object in following form { "data-order" : [ HTMLElement:tr_1 , HTMLElement:tr_2 ]
3. Then empty all the rows on the table
4. Get the key set from the Object created on step 2
5. Sort it
6. Print it ( note each element on your object could have more than one object, if you allow duplicate data-order values)

```js
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var new_tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
var tr_list = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows;
var tr_list_obj = {};
for(var tr_index in tr_list){
 var tr = tr_list[tr_index];
 if(tr instanceof HTMLElement){
   if(tr_list_obj[tr.getAttribute("data-order")] instanceof Array){
     tr_list_obj[tr.getAttribute("data-order")].push(tr);
    }else{
     tr_list_obj[tr.getAttribute("data-order")] = new Array();
     tr_list_obj[tr.getAttribute("data-order")].push(tr);
    }
  }
}


tr_list[0].parentNode.innerHTML = '';


tr_list_sort_array = Object.keys(tr_list_obj);
tr_list_sort_array.sort();

for(var tr_index in tr_list_sort_array){
 for(var tr_index_2 in tr_list_obj[tr_list_sort_array[tr_index]]){
    table.appendChild(tr_list_obj[tr_list_sort_array[tr_index]][tr_index_2]);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr data-order='2'><td>First 2</td></tr>
<tr data-order='1'><td>First 1</td></tr>
<tr data-order='3'><td>First 3</td></tr>
<tr data-order='5'><td>First 5</td></tr>
<tr data-order='4'><td>First 4</td></tr>
<tr data-order='9'><td>First 9</td></tr>
<tr data-order='4'><td>Second 4</td></tr>
<tr data-order='1'><td>Second 1</td></tr>
<tr data-order='3'><td>Second 3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Its working, but the problem is that the tr of my thead move to the end.

Comment: Hmm since original tr list didnt had any tbody or thead I assumed you wouldnt have them. But you could remove it and then append later just before you appending <tr> list. Better method would be on the last last for loop instead of using table use HTMLElement tbody

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 $('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
  var contentA = parseInt($(a).data('order'));
  var contentB = parseInt($(b).data('order'));
  return (contentA < contentB) ? -1 : (contentA > contentB) ? 1 : 0;
 })
```

run it after adding a new row

and check [Array.prototype.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Answer (score 1):

you will not be be able to sort in place. So need to detach and append.

1) get the parent and list of  TRs

2) sort TRs

3) detach and append TRs

```
var $table = $('table'),
$tr = $table.children('tr');

$tr.sort(function(a,b){
    var an = Number(a.data('order')),
       bn = Number(b.data('order'));

    if(an > bn) {
        return 1;
    }
    if(an < bn) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
});

$tr.detach().appendTo($table);
```

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is:

walk throu all [rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/rows) in table, if index if row dosn't match right `data-order` [move it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) it to right place.